# Regex for a math style expression with '=' or '!=' operator

Tags: python, regex

I apologise in advance if the title of this question is not accurate enough, I have tried my best to illustrate with an example and short explanation below:

I am trying to write a regular expression that can identify an expression in any of the following forms:

```
name=value

name!=value

name

!name

!name=value

!name!=value
```

I have devised to following regex, which works pretty well, except for when the first operand (name) starts with a '!'.

```
import re
expressionRe = re.compile( r"^(?P<name>[^=|^\!=]+)(?P<operator>(\!=|=*))(?P<value>.*)$" ) 

def showGroups( expr ):                                                                                             
   exprMatch = expressionRe.match( expr )                                                                                   
   if not exprMatch:                                                                                                
      print "no match"                                                                                             
   else:                 
      print "Name: {0}, operator: {1}, value {2}".\
         format( exprMatch.group('name'),
                 exprMatch.group('operator'),
                 exprMatch.group('value') )      

showGroups('abc!=')          
Name: abc, operator: !=, value:  

showGroups('.*=')            
Name: .*, operator: =, value:    

showGroups('.*=abc')         
Name: .*, operator: =, value: abc

showGroups('.*=val')         
Name: .*, operator: =, value: val

showGroups('=')  // this is expected
no match         

showGroups('!abc')  // this doesn't work :(
no match
```

I realise I have made the first capture group not allow the first operand (name) to start with a '!', but this is the closest working example that I can get to demonstrate all the other cases working properly.

Was wondering if someone could help me out with the last part, getting name to be able to start with '!', without breaking the operator group may start with '!' if it is followed by an '=' sign.

Thank you in advance for any tips or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Regex: `^(?P<not>!)?(?P<name>[^=!]+)?(?P<operator>!?=)?(?P<value>(?<==).+)?$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CxZ0Jk/2)

Comment: Thanks @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi, I didn't look at that part, as I was focusing mostly on the requirement.. I've fixed it...

Answer (score 1):

Your negated character `[^=|^\!=]+` set are not written correctly. Most meta characters loose their special meaning when they are written within character set. I think you want to write an expression that match any character except `=` and `!` for which writing this `[^=!]` is enough and also since `!` is not a special character in regex, you don't need to escape it and escaping within character set is not needed anyway and after correction your corrected regex becomes following. Also, I've captured `!` character in `notoperator` group optionally appearing at the start of line and your final regex becomes this,

```
^(?P<notoperator>!)?(?P<name>[^=!\n]+)(?P<operator>(!?=))?(?P<value>.*)$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aXjPgs/4)**

Comment: I am still losing the '!' at the start of the first operand this way though.

e.g. !name=value is interpreted the same as name=value

Comment: @bwrabbit: Where do you want to capture `!` at the start? in some fourth named group other than three that you already have? In your code in your post, you only seem to be interested in capturing `name`, `operator` and `value`. Where do you want to capture the `!` at the start?

Comment: In a fourth name group would be ideal,  although either would work for my use   case. Thanks again for the help I appreciate the  insightful feedback!

Comment: @bwrabbit: Sure, of course that `!` can be captured in fourth group, I just matched it using `.*?` so as to match your string and intentionally didn't capture it any group as you didn't seem to be interested in capturing that seeing your current code in post. Let me update my regex to capture that.

Comment: @bwrabbit: I've updated my answer to capture that `!` into a new group `notoperator` and now only `name` group is mandatory and rest are optional like you wanted in your post. Hence, any of the sample will match as long as name group has something to capture. Also, as in your examples in post, for `=` it should say `no match` so it won't match and rest all samples will match and print correct output as captured in groups.